# none of the versions of content item is visible in Sitecore CMS 7.1

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore

We are facing very weird issue in Sitecore CMS site, we are unable to see the content of the item in any version any language in content tree.Even the templates fields are missing. Earlier it was working absolutely fine we were able to view all the items in content tree in all languages. We couln't find any thing in the sitecore log although we queried Master DB and the items are there in different version in item table.
We restored the master DB and after that everything is back to normal but the content is lost for that specific period which was uploaded by content author. We are still looking for the root cause of the issue because client is very much scared if this problem occurs again in future. Any help will be appreciated. Site is already in UAT phase and eveything is working fine.

**Screenshots:**

*Content Editor*
[image: Content Editor Screenshot]

*dbbrowser.aspx*
[image: dbbrowser.aspx Screenshot]

Comment: Do you have the backup of the corrupted database? Can you attach the screenshot from the content editor? Can you try to view the content using `/sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx` application?

Comment: Please find the attached screenshot for same.                                                            .

Comment: @Marek ..Please find the attached screenshot for ContentEditor from  : http://snag.gy/oETOl.jpg  and from  dbbrowser.aspx http://snag.gy/1Kiff.jpg

Comment: I would also check the recycle bin in the corrupted database to see if anything has been deleted.

Comment: @Ian....I already checked in Recycle Bin for master DB...It's empty

Comment: One thing I observed in master DB that data are there in Item,Versionfields and Fields tables but the data from Language column of these tables are missing. Is there any guess what is the root cause or how can we retrieve back the language?

Comment: Did you just upgrade from a Sitecore 6.X site? If so, what version (including revision number)?

Comment: @Zachary...This site was initially developed in 6.6 and been upgraded in version 7.1 approx 8 months back

Comment: We restored the DB from backup and after that we are not facing this issue from last one week, still looking for root cause.Why data in different language got silently disappeared of all content items?Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Thnx for all support.....it seems the issue was with GPI connector....it was triggering event while pushing the content back to sitecore and there it's lost the language of content item somehow....Although our system is back but we are still monitoring.....